# c++ IF statements execute, but adding ELSE shows errors

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm supposed to be using nested if/else statements in my assignment.  My IF statements execute just fine, but when I add "else" anywhere it comes up with a red squiggly line under it. Is it because I'm using the brackets wrong?

```
{
const int package = 99;
double quantity, total1, total2, total4;

cout << "How many units were sold?\n";
cin >> quantity;

if (quantity >= 1 && quantity <= 19);
{
total1 = package * quantity - (.2 * package * quantity);
cout << "Sale total: " << total1 << endl;
}

else if (quantity >= 20 && quantity <= 99);
{
total2 = package * quantity - (.3 * package * quantity);
cout << "Sale total: " << total2 << endl;
}

else (quantity >= 100);
{
total4 = package * quantity - (.5 * package * quantity);
cout << "Sale total: " << total4 << endl;
}
```

The errors I'm getting back from the lines using "else" are:

- E0127 expected a statement
- C2181 illegal else without matching if

Comment: '`else (quantity >= 100);` should read `else if  (quantity >= 100)`

Comment: I would propose that your `if` statements do **not** function just fine. Did you test the case where the condition is supposed to be false before you tried adding `else` clauses?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are putting semicolons at the end of your if statements, and before the opening bracket. The last else is missing an if, but I beleive that you don't event need a condition here at all. Also I see an opening bracket at the top without one at the end, but I assume that is due to bad copy/pasting the code. The correct code would look like that:

```cpp
if (quantity >= 1 && quantity <= 19)
{
total1 = package * quantity - (.2 * package * quantity);
cout << "Sale total: " << total1 << endl;
}

else if (quantity >= 20 && quantity <= 99)
{
total2 = package * quantity - (.3 * package * quantity);
cout << "Sale total: " << total2 << endl;
}

else
{
total4 = package * quantity - (.5 * package * quantity);
cout << "Sale total: " << total4 << endl;
}
```

Comment: What you say about the `else` not needing a test is only true the the user enters a positive integral value.   However, the variable `quantity` is of type `double`    The `else` will therefore catch values less than `1.0`, between `19.0 and `20.0` (not inclusive).   There is nothing preventing the user entering such values.   Admittedly, coding errors aside, that's true of the OP's code, but removing the last test for `quantity >= 100` does mean more values pass into the `else`.

Comment: @Peter What you said is correct, but I don't think it's really relevant here. OP is obviously just starting out with a simple program, and for now he probably shouldn't worry about that. You could also argue that a quantity is never supposed to be negative. However that is a valid point to take into consideration for improvement further down the line.

Comment: Thank you! That was it!

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to put a semicolon after the conditions of `if`s. Also, it doesn't make sense to have a condition on an `else` that's not an `else if`.

Comment: Might also be worth noting the reason that the first block runs (semicolon terminates the conditional, block statement is entered normally)

Comment: @HotelCalifornia That doesn't happen in this case, because the dangling `else`s cause compile errors that prevent it from getting that far.

Comment: per the OP: "My IF statements execute just fine, but when I add "else" anywhere it comes up with a red squiggly line"

Comment: @HotelCalifornia Ah, you're right. I missed that and was just looking at the code.